# Ubuntu Server on HP ProLiant ML350P G8?

Tags: server, hp

I wonder if it's possible to run Ubuntu Server on my server?

```
HP ProLiant ML350P Gen8 (G8)

 - 2x Intel Xeon E5-2690 2.9GHz 20MB Cache 8-Core Processor

 - 192GB DDR3 ECC

 - HP Smart Array P420 512MB + FBWC
```

Do I have to install the LTS version of Ubuntu Server?

Should I choose 14.04, 16.04 or 17.10?

Is it OK to install Ubuntu Server on bare metal?

Comment: Your hardware supports any Ubuntu release/flavour, server or desktop. LTS releases are supported for 5 years and that alone is a great advantage but it's not in any way "mandatory" to install a LTS. 17.10 is not LTS.

Comment: Is the HP Smart Array P420 supported? I have read something about ML350e HP Dynamic Smart Array B120i have issues on Ubuntu Server...

Comment: Is it recommended to install Ubuntu Server on bare metal or is ESXi better?